# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote a procedure which actually searches a record.
when i execute it, it gives an error which says:

> *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

Statement:

```
((CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(YYYY, Tbl_Contract.ContractDate), 101)) = @Year or @Year = '')
```

Comment: whats -1 for? no comments yet..

Comment: ContractDate is a Datetime field?

Comment: NO, it is not datetime field, ContractDate is varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ContractDate` is a `Varchar` you can either parse `directly` with

```
SubString(ContractDate, x, 4) = @YearString
```

or you can encapsulate the condition

```
Case when IsDate(ContractDate) = 1 
      then ((CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(YYYY, @a), 101))) 
      else NULL 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are converting the date to a year value :

```
DATEPART(YYYY,@ContractDate)
```

and then trying to convert that back to a date :

```
CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(YYYY, @ContractDate),101)
```

You might try this : **EDIT**

```
datepart(yyyy, CONVERT(datetime, @ContractDate))
```

Comment: ContractDate is a varchar field, not a datetime,

Comment: Exactly. This will convert it to a datetime from a varchar.